# How do you calculate the 95% confidence interval between 2 percentages, without knowing n?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference

I am trying to figure out a statistics homework question, and I am unsure where to start ...

I am pretty sure that I need to identify a confidence interval, and then note if the country is outside that confidence interval. That way, if the H0 were true (they are the same), and we chose to reject H0, that would reflect the Type 1 error.

However, n is unknown, and I am pretty sure the question (given the marking status) is not looking for me to calculate "each" country independently.

Any direction would be appreciated !!

Question:

If in fact there has been no change in the atheism index in the countries listed in Table 4, in how many of those countries would you expect to detect a change (at a significance level of 0.05) simply by chance?
Hint: Look in the textbook index under Type 1 error.

I am pretty sure that I need to identify what the confidence intervals are, and then note if the country is outside that confidence interval. That way, if the H0 were true (they are the same), and we chose to reject H0, that would reflect the Type 1 error.

However, n is unknown, and I am pretty sure the question (given the marking status) is not looking for me to calculate "each" country independently, but more on a whole basis.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood the question. Think more generally about what the hint is referring to.

The definition of a Type 1 Error is to incorrectly conclude that there has been a change when in fact there was no change. If we're using a significance level of 0.05, that means our probability of making a Type 1 Error is 5%.

> If there has been no change, then the probability of detecting a change is 5% for each country.

> If there are $n$ countries in Table 4 and each has probability 0.05 of detecting a change, what is the distribution of the total number of changes detected? What is the expected value of that distribution?

Comment: These are scarcely "spoilers."  Consider setting them in ordinary type.  Then, please consider explaining the implicit assumptions you are making with your last statement -- particularly your interpretation that the question is asking for an expectation.  (Another interpretation is that it is asking for the full distribution of the counts.)

Comment: @whuber I think not everyone will go back and re-read to make sure they understand the intermediate logic. So, putting spoiler tags to encourage the reader to stop and think is reasonable, but this is a matter of taste. You make a good point about considering the full distribution, although I think the question asking "how many ... would you expect" is a pretty strong indication that they're looking for a number.

Comment: This really helped me to understand what the question was asking - thank you for helping to clarify.